Unpack multiple tgz files in one directory with Maven Truezip Plugin
I have a Maven-Build in which I only package an Umbrella-Helm-Chart that has other Helm-Charts as dependencies. To automatically generate the values.schema.json file I want to use the helm-schema executable. I do not want to configure the filenames of the tgz files of the dependencies in the pom.xml because the versions can change with each release and are already maintained in the Charts.yaml of the Umbrella-Helm-Chart.
I have to unpack the dependencies in the charts folder before using the helm-schema executable. I found the truezip-maven-plugin but am not able to unpack all tgz files in one directory with just one execution of the Truezip-Maven-Plugin. I also tried to use ther iterator-maven-plugin but failed also.
Can somebody please help me?
Here is what my Truezip-plugin-configuration looks like:
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>extract-helm-chart-dependencies</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${helm.chart.target.directory.complete}/charts/</directory>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dest</outputDirectory>
                            </fileset>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

In the directory ${helm.chart.target.directory.complete}/charts/ are the .tgz files which should get unpacked to  ${project.build.directory}/dest.
I also tried something like this, with using a mapper but am not able to get it to work:
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        <configuration>
                            <fileset>
                                <directory>${helm.chart.target.directory.complete}/charts/</directory>
                                <mapper type="glob" from="*.tgz/*yaml" to="*"/> 
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dest</outputDirectory>
                            </fileset>
                        </configuration>
                        .
                        .
                        .

I already tried using the maven-iterator-plugin. But there is only a mechanism where one can configure a folder and the iterator-plugin iterates over the subfolders. tgz files are not recognized as subfolders by this plugin, so this does not work for me.
